# RedShift: Simple insert Queries are not running on concurrent cluster

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have added concurrent cluster support for our redshift cluster. It runs select queries in case of high load.

I have below questions:

1. Does it give the higher priority to read queries over write?
2. We have simple insert statement, but they are not being picked up by concurrent cluster. what could be the possible reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, concurrent clusters are designed to run read-only queries as the master copy of the data remains on the main cluster AND a limited set of write queries.  A full list of these write limitations are given at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/concurrency-scaling.html

Also, since concurrent clusters are remote from the source data there is an inherent cost to run queries on these clusters.  Simple queries generally won't gain enough from the concurrent cluster's resource availability to overcome these costs for short, simple queries.

What you are seeing seems quite normal from my Redshift experience.